# ubuntu 13.10 virtual box usb

Tags: 13.10, usb, windows-7, virtualbox

i have win7x64 as a guest OS on my virtual box 4.2.16.

usb is not **displayed** on explorer on the guest OS even after choosing the 
appropriate from  **devices**  menu

Comment: Is it showing in the device manager?

Comment: ya it is displayed with ** code 10 error this device cannot start **

Comment: Is it a usual thumb drive?

Comment: Try adding yourself to the Virtual Box users group in Users and Groups

Comment: @davidbaumann yup it is it used to work for xp sp-3

Comment: @C.S.Cameron i am a member of vboxusers groups

Comment: Is it working with xp right now?

Comment: @davidbaumann s it is!!

Comment: You can try to reinstall the tools...

Comment: @davidbaumann reinstalling tools did not help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands:

```
VBoxManage list usbhost ## command 1 
VBoxManage list vms ## command 2
```

With the information from these two commands, run the following:

```
VBoxManage usbfilter add 0 -target <vmsnumber> -name <[0000]> -action hold -active yes -vendorid <0x0000> -productid <0x0000>
```

replacing the `<>` items with their respective values from the commands 1 & 2. Let us know what the command returns.